# Correct permissions for sudo LAMP /var/www directory

Tags: permissions, sudo, directory

I am trying to set permissions with

```
sudo 775 - R  /var/www/
```

on all folders and all files in the `www` folder of lamp for `sudo user`.

Is this the correct way to set up the system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper permission under /var/www/ is **755** for **folders** and **644** for **files**.

- The value for  **755** is **readable** by **User**, **Group**, and **World**, **writable** by **User**, **executable** by **User**, **Group**, and **World**. For uploading folder it should be different, and you should change manually.
- Whereas the value for **644** is **readable** by **User**, **Group**,
  and **World**, but **writable** only by **User**.

The short command to set folder and file under /var/www/ to 755 and 644 is:

```
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 

find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

These are simple commands so you will get all folder and files into these permissions, of course, that is not the best practice, it would better if you set spesifically the folders or files that you want to set (I edit this answers after considering comments from **AzkerM**).

Comment: Assigning 644 to the whole root in `/var/www` directory is not a good practice though. Instead OP can try assigning permissions to the necessary directories as needed.

Comment: It would be better if you describe in a structured, so everyone will know how best we should do :) That includes me will learn from it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your answer but it is always better to add a precaution advising the OP about the permissions. After all, the whole `www` directory will face the public. A simple permission issue can cause lots of problems. Keep up your good work. :)

Comment: Thank you **AzkerM** for your suggestion, I have edited my answers, thank you again :)