# Access forbidden 403 error in xampp

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, xampp

I am very new to xampp. I have made a fresh xampp install with the following commands.

```
sudo su
cd /tmp
wget bit.ly/1cmyrUo -O xampp-32bit.run
chmod 777 ./xampp-32bit.run
sudo ./xampp-32bit.run
```

Then I made a perl file to check whether my xampp works. The following is my `sample.pl` file content.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
print "content-type:text/html\n";
print(header());
use CGI qw(:standard);
print(start_html());
print "Hello. I am ram";
print(end_html());
```

After copying my perl file from `/home/vicky/desktop` to `/opt/lampp/cgi-bin`.

I started my xampp with the following command.

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Then I ran my `sample.pl` in the localhost with the help of the `http://localhost/cgi-bin/sample.pl` in my mozilla browser. I just got the following window.
[image: Error 403 window]

I found only answers relating to the 'new security concept error' and 'accessing virtual host issue'.

I did came across an [askubuntu query](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336177/i-have-403-forbidden-error-run-xampp), a bid similar to that of mine. It had no answers but some comments. One comment suggested to change the file permissions. It directed to get help from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450603/correct-permissions-for-sudo-lamp-var-www-directory/465580#465580).

It said to change the directory permission as 755 and file permission as 644 to resolve this kind of issue. When I tried to do that, I came to know that my cgi-bin directory already had 755 permission and my `sample.pl` had 644 permission. I have no solutions now.

---

PostScript: I have attached the content of my **/opt/lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf** file. Hope this will help the answer-providers to understand my problem completely.

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` instead of installing xampp manually.

Comment: 403 forbidden means that your are not allow to access that page. Could you post your apache configuration? Also try this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/499943/cgi-bin-does-not-seem-to-be-set-up)

Comment: @Letizia: Where is my apache configuration?

Comment: @Ranviqnesh: should be in the directory /your/path/xampp/apache/conf

Comment: Did you post the entire file or only a portion? Could you check if there are other file in `/opt/lampp/apache2/conf` or in `/opt/lampp/apache2/sites-available`. If you find 00-default.conf, could you post its content? You could use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @Letizia: Yes. I did had just this much in my httpd.conf file. Then, I don't have sites-available. As well, I don't have 00-default.conf anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see in your question, you are using **Apache 2.4.7**, but your httpd.conf use **Apache 2.2** directive.

According to [**Apache 2.4**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) manual:

> Access control
>
> In 2.2, access control based on client hostname, IP address, and other
>   characteristics of client requests was done using the directives
>   Order, Allow, Deny, and Satisfy.
>
> In 2.4, such access control is done in the same way as other
>   authorization checks, using the new module mod_authz_host. The old
>   access control idioms should be replaced by the new authentication
>   mechanisms, although for compatibility with old configurations, the
>   new module mod_access_compat is provided.

Try this changes:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Allow** and **deny** directive controls which hosts can or can't access an area of the server, **Require** tests whether an authenticated user is authorized according to a particular authorization provider and the specified restrictions. **Require all granted** means access is allowed unconditionally, let see [Beyond just authorization](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html#beyond)

**Update** after reading configuration file:

Your default configuration file is right. The problem is wrong shebang in perl script.

Try this:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
```

Also:

```
  chmod +x /opt/lampp/cgi-bin/yourScript.pl
```

[Here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied) is a useful link about file permission problem

**Second update**

Change http content header:

```
  print "Content-type:text/html\n";
```

This header is read by apache.

You apache is running as `daemon` user, check if each directory in script path are readable.

Comment: New changes does show the same error message!

Comment: So there must be other configuration files, is there `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf` file? Try find `/opt/lampp -name "*.conf"` and check if these file are apache conf file

Comment: I have found `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`. But there is no `<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">` section. I have attached my httpd-xampp.conf file [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7940780/). Please see through it.

Comment: @Ramviqnesh: okey, this file is a part of configuration, I think that there are other file, in any case, did you get same error if you try to access a simple index.php at http://localhost?

Comment: It is not showing any error. When I enter `http://localhost/index.php`, the url turns into `http://localhost/xampp/`. Then, the **XAMPP for Linux** page is getting opened.

Comment: Thi means that there is an http redirection. It is necessary find out the main apache configuration file. Try this command: 'find /opt/lampp -name "*.conf" -exec grep DocumentRoot {} \; -print'

Comment: I have tried `find /opt/lampp -name "*.conf" -exec grep DocumentRoot {} \; -print`. And I have pasted its result [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8118048/). Please look through it.

Comment: Could you post: /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf and /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf? And also "ls /opt/lampp/etc /opt/lampp/etc/extra" output.

Comment: [/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8123782/); [/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8123756/); [ls /opt/lampp/etc /opt/lampp/etc/extra](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8123734/).

Comment: Updeted answer, sorry, I have not noticed before

Comment: Changed my shebang and done +x to the file permissions. Still I find the 403 error.

Comment: Updated answer, if it will not work again, check if perl script print a well formed html output and please post /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-default.conf, /opt/lampp/etc/extra/proxy-html.conf and /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf

Comment: @Ramvignesh, I'm curious, did you finally resolve the issue?

Comment: Sorry ya. My brother mistakenly overwritten my ubuntu os with a windows 8. I have installed a new copy of ubuntu now. need to install xampp again.

Comment: When I installed xampp last time, I did it [this way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/507844/xampp-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04/507857#507857). Shall do the same now ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know, If you need help on how is the best way to install xampp, try to ask an other question, someone else will help you for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing owner and group for the files to apache,

In ubuntu the apache user is www-data, in terminal:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data PUBLICFOLDER
```

And refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem,you should upgrade xampp to last version

- https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

And Run apache again it will run correctly.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cd /opt/lampp
$ sudo chmod 777 -R htdocs
```

And edit `httpd.conf` (with something like `sudoedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`) and change:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: and configure--> httpd.conf

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: Allowing read+write+execute to every user is a bad idea.