# Xampp installation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity

I am using ubuntu 14.04. I want to install lampp but don't know how to install it. Can I get some help for installing lampp on my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 32-bit architecture follow these commands. . .

```
cd /tmp
wget bit.ly/1cmyrUo -O xampp-32bit.run
chmod 777 xampp-32bit.run
sudo ./xampp-32bit.run
```

---

For a 64-bit architecture, these. . .

```
cd /tmp
wget bit.ly/1cmyrUo -O xampp-64bit.run
chmod 777 xampp-64bit.run
sudo ./xampp-64bit.run
```

---

PostScript: Try these commands from the root. You can get into the root mode with `sudo su` command.

Comment: No I am using 64-bit architecure should I follow the same instruction by making 32 as 64.

Comment: Give it a shot yaar. . . If it works, improve my answer. Else, notify me. I'll provide you with some other solution.

Comment: So, replacing 32 with 64 had worked for you, right? Are you sure? Shall I improve the answer?

Comment: yes. it worked.

Comment: -1 This installs XAMPP, *not LAMPP*. Apparently it worked to OP's expectations though.

Comment: 301 Moved permanently; the new address "can't be translated".

Comment: Not a worth answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already installed an Ubuntu 14.04 desktop edition, you can install the popular  web stack by running this command :

From the root account :

```
# apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql libapache2-mod-perl2 libapache-session-perl libapache2-authcookie-perl
```

Or from a sudoer user account :

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql libapache2-mod-perl2 libapache-session-perl libapache2-authcookie-perl
```

Note that :

- `#` is the symbol of the root command line prompt
- `$` is the symbol of the regular user command line prompt
- you have not to copy this symbol to run the command, begin your command by `apt-get ...` or `sudo ...`

In addition, you could want to install PhpMyAdmin to administrate you MySql database from your web browser :

```
$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Then, you may have to create a symbolic link to access to PhpMyAdmin user interface from `http://172.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` or `http://172.0.1.1/phpmyadmin` or `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` (assuming you use the default `/var/www` folder as DocumentRoot in your apache configuration):

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

After installation, the main configuration files for apache2 will be here :

- `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
- `/etc/apache2/sites-available`
- `/etc/apache2/mods-available`
- `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

Php configuration file for Apache is there :

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Enabling CGI-perl :

```
$ sudo a2enmod cgi
```

Enabling SSL :

```
$ sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Enabling URL rewriting module (often required for installing CMS or using MVC PHP frameworks) :

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

When you change some configurations in /etc files, or enabling modules (a2enmod ...), you must reload or restart your Apache server :

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

or 
    $ sudo service apache2 restart

are aliases of

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

and

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: apache2 is not running, error : sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error l

Comment: The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                         [fail]
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems

Comment: Can I remove some of the packages that I installed because I don't need them & they are interrupting in my work, if yes pls tell me how do I remove the packages completely except xampp. pls help me.

Comment: The simple way may be to run `sudo apt-get remove --purge package1 package2 package3` etc ... Before, save the config files that you have change in order to restore them if needed.

Answer (score 1):

DigitalOcean explains very best way to install **LAMP stack**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

**STEPS:**

Install Apache

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Install MySQL

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql
```

need to tell MySQL to create its database directory structure where it will store its information

```
sudo mysql_install_db
```

Install PHP

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

In most cases, we'll want to modify the way that Apache serves files when a directory is requested. Currently, if a user requests a directory from the server, Apache will first look for a file called index.html. We want to tell our web server to prefer PHP files, so we'll make Apache look for an index.php file first.

To do this, type this command to open the dir.conf file in a text editor with root privileges:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

It will look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

We want to move the PHP index file highlighted above to the first position after the DirectoryIndex specification, like this:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

When you are finished, save and close the file by pressing "CTRL-X". You'll have to confirm the save by typing "Y" and then hit "ENTER" to confirm the file save location.

After this, we need to restart the Apache web server in order for our changes to be recognized. You can do this by typing this:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Install PHP Modules

```
apt-cache search php5-
```

**Now you're done installing.**

also find how to enable **phpmyadmin**:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @Melebius You're right..I'll update mu answer

Comment: @Melebius I have update the answer.